# HP ProLiant BL460c Configuring Memory

Tags: performance, hp-proliant

I hope you can help me.

I need to install 48GB of RAM in an HP BL460c G1. The CPU is 48W, and I've researched the specification and I can do it for this kind of processor.

I've also read the basic rules for putting memory in the slots, but I have doubts.

I have 4 x 2GB and 4 x 4GB. What is the best configuration?

Bank 1A: 2GB
Bank 2C: 2GB
Bank 3A: 2GB
Bank 4C: 2GB
Bank 5B: 8GB
Bank 6D: 8GB
Bank 7B: 8GB
Bank 8D: 8GB

or

Bank 1A: 2GB
Bank 2C: 8GB
Bank 3A: 2GB
Bank 4C: 8GB
Bank 5B: 2GB
Bank 6D: 8GB
Bank 7B: 2GB
Bank 8D: 8GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only DIMM population rules are listed in the [Quickspecs](http://vb.net/products/HP/12518_div.html#Memory) for the HP ProLiant BL460c G1 server.

```
DIMM installation guidelines:
1. All DIMMs must be PC2-5300 Fully Buffered DIMMs at 667 MHz.
2. Both DIMM slots in a memory bank must be populated.
3. Banks must be populated in sequential alphabetic order, starting with bank A.
4. Both DIMMs in a memory bank must be identical. Install identical DIMMs as pairs only.
```

Comment: thanks, for your answer. I read those basic rules, and the examples are based on those rules. But my question is directly given this "Heaviest load (DIMM with most ranks) within a channel goes furthest from the processor". For that reason i have a doubt how to populate the banks B and C, the banks A y D is OK.

Comment: DIMM ranks and loads aren't relevant to this server model and vintage. The language you mention isn't part of the memory guidelines for this server.

Comment: your right, that rule isn't for that kind of server. So based in the four rules below, no matter the capacity of the memory for populate the bank and is the same 
Bank C: 2GB y D: 8GB and Bank C:8GB and D:2GB
thanks a lot